# Three level CSS menu with first layer in horizontal layout

Tags: html, css, layout, html-lists

What I'm after is to have the top level `ul li`s laid out horizontally, and then subsequent levels laid out vertically, preferably indented slightly as levels go down, under their parent `li`.

Not after any hover functionality, just a nice layout, something like this:

```
Top Item 1       Top Item 2      Top Item 3
 sub item 1       sub item 1      sub item 1
 sub item 2       sub item 2      sub item 2
  sub sub item 1  sub item 3      sub item 3
  sub sub item 2  sub item 4      sub item 4
 sub item 5       sub item 5      sub item 5
```

Comment: A footer menu? Like a footer on the bottom of the page? And the sub items, are they shown all the time or just on hover and popping upwards?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, footer at the bottom of the page. And yes, sub menus to show all the time. I know it sounds like an odd thing to want, but there is method in my madness..... maybe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a copy-paste stuff to play with:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    li.level1 { float: left; display: inline; margin-right: 20px }
    ul.level2 { display: inline }
    li.level2 { display: block; padding-left: 20px }
    ul.level3 { display: inline }
    li.level3 { display: block; padding-left: 20px }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="level1">
    <li class="level1">apple</li>
    <li class="level1">banana
        <ul class="level2">
            <li class="level2">banana 1
                <ul class="level3">
                    <li class="level3">banana 1 A</li>
                    <li class="level3">banana 1 B</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="level2">banana 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level1">cherry
        <ul class="level2">
            <li class="level2">cherry 1</li>
            <li class="level2">cherry 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level1">dddd</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/XtUEs/)

**CSS:**

```
#footer {
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ddd
}
.outer {
    list-style: none;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.first {
    font-weight: bold
}
.outer ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 18px
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul class="outer">
        <li class="first"><a href="#">Top Item 1</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="outer">
        <li class="first"><a href="#">Top Item 2</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="outer">
        <li class="first"><a href="#">Top Item 3</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: That looks just the job... Big thanks all. I'm real brain dead today and you've helped me out big style.

Comment: Why do you make a new UL for every top menu item? That defeats the original purpose of UL.

Comment: @Dercsár: No particular reason. I just didn't think about it quite hard enough, and I guess I read a part of the question wrongly "top level ul’s" - it doesn't actually say that.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want something pure css then how about something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/pLFqd/2/

**Edit:** Missed the bit about not wanting hover functionality, try simple example attached

Comment: I don't think the question asker wants a JS menu: "sub menus to show all the time".